# PSWindowsUpdate can't hide an update

Tags: powershell

My goal is to hide 3 specifics updates out from Windows Update on Windows 7. I'm simply using PSWindowsUpdate in order to do it.
Updates are the followings :
KB3175024
KB3172605
KB3167679

What I can do :
**Get-WUList -MicrosoftUpdate** : Display available updates to install
**Hide-WUUpdate -KBArticleID "KB3175024" -MicrosoftUpdate -confirm:$false** : Hide the update : KB3175024

The issue :
When I type **Get-WUList -MicrosoftUpdate** the update **KB3167679** don't appear in the list. When I look for this one from the GUI in Windows Update, it's showed up in the important updates.
The real problem is that I can't hide this specific update like this : **Hide-WUUpdate -KBArticleID "KB3167679" -MicrosoftUpdate -confirm:$false**: does strictly nothing.

Any clue ?

Comment: I have same essue in 2020/4/10 Microsoft Silverlight (KB4481252).

Answer (score 2):

The following syntax was tested under powershell v4 successfully:

```
$HideUpdatesArray=('KB3175024', 'KB3172605', 'KB3167679')
```

*Hide without confirmation:*

```
Hide-WUUpdate -KBArticleID $HideUpdatesArray -HideStatus:$true -Confirm:$false
```

*Unhide without confirmation:*

```
Hide-WUUpdate -KBArticleID $HideUpdatesArray -HideStatus:$false -Confirm:$false
```